# php file_put_contents() replaces '+' with space

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'm trying to overwrite a file using php function `file_put_contents()`  along with ajax, how ever while writing to the file the plus sign (+) is replace with a space. Here is the code snippet

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div>inline editor will change this text</div>
        <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">save changes</button>
    <script>
        function loadDoc() {
            var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.open("POST", "overwrite.php", true);
            xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhttp.send("html="+html.outerHTML);  
            <!--the + here is replace with a space-->
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Basically what i'm trying to do here is to allow the user to use inline editors to change the text and then get the updated DOM and write it back to the file, overwriting the previous content.

Here is `overwrite.php`

```
<?php
    $var = $_POST['html'];
    file_put_contents("index.php", $var );
?>
```

There are two things going wrong with this actually

1). the + symbol is being replace with a space (solved thanks to simultaneous answers by @deceze @Justinas)

2). there are style tags being added inside the  head tag (still unsolved and mighty annoying)

it would be great to find out what is actually happening here, and maybe i  could alter the code to fix it.

I'm well aware of the security risks of allowing users to modify content and then writing it directly to a file, i'm just experimenting here.

thanks

Comment: application/x-www-form-urlencoded will change your + to space. You can try urldecode($var) in overwrite.php

Comment: @Undefined_variable Nope, that's a) fixing it on the wrong end and b) you'd be double-decoding the data, which can only make things worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are sending plain text via `GET`. In URL `+` means space so when PHP reads URL string it automatically url-decodes it and your `+` is replaced with space. Use `xhttp.send('html='+encodeURIComponent(html.outerHTML))`.
2. Are you using any framework or any other automated system to auto-append styles?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, it worked like a charm!! and no i'm not using any frameworks just plain php, i suspect its the outerHTML that is adding this?

Comment: if you could help me with the style tag auto append part, you would have the edge over the other answer ;P +1 for the answer though

Comment: @lensemagnifique In your provided code I see no clues why *#2*

Comment: @lensemagnifique I don't think it's all your code, because of `inline editor`. It may be adding it's CSS to header. Otherwise you will see no elements of editor.

Comment: i was planning to add ckeditor in the future, but not added it yet, but fair enough this solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`+` in the [`x-www-form-urlencoded` format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) *means* space! You need to correctly url-encode your content before sending it to the server:

```
xhttp.send("html=" + encodeURIComponent(html.outerHTML));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, it worked like a charm!! could also look into why the style tags are being added?

Comment: I have nowhere near enough information to figure that out for you.